# Libgdx: Why doesn't the mouse click event Buttons.LEFT register?

Tags: java, libgdx

For some reason unknown to me, when I use Buttons.LEFT with an event handler, nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Buttons.LEFT)) {
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked!");
}
```

If I do, say, Keys.LEFT, or justTouched(), the message prints, but not when I do Buttons.LEFT. And yes, I'm 100% I'm pressing my mouse button, and that it works correctly. ;)

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because Gdx.input.isKeyPressed() is for Keyboard input.  If you want mouse button input you should be doing

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)){
    System.out.println("Mouse clicked!");
}
```

Buttons and Keys are different classes, and as such have matching methods in input.  Explore the Input API Javadocs of theirs a bit more, it's helped me quite a lot.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html

Comment: That would make a lot of sense! I completely overlooked that. Thanks a lot.